# XSL Xpath to get last element and not equal to 0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml

```
<root>
<flow>0</flow> 
<flow>0</flow>
<flow>0</flow> 
<flow>0</flow>
<flow>10</flow> 
<flow>0</flow>
</root
```

I need to get the last element . But if last is 0 then the immediate flow value which is not equl to 0 . In my case here it is 10
I am trying to avoid the usage of for-each

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the XPath expression `/root/flow[. != 0][last()]`.